# Creating REST API controller on top of Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, asynchronous, firebase-admin

I'm trying to build REST API controller(using spring boot framework) on top of **Firebase admin sdk**, but I'm facing following issue:

Suppose, if I receive a **GET** request and it needs to read data from *Firebase Realtime Database* and returns as response for that **GET** request. Reading data from *Firebase Realtime Database* is possible only using **asynchronous listeners**, so how can I implement this:

- Do I need to wait until the *asynchronous* call completes to give the response for that **GET** request ?(If yes any samples)
- Or any other best practise to follow here ?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this should work:

```
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final AtomicReference<Object> value = new AtomicReference<>(null);
    final AtomicReference<Exception> exception = new AtomicReference<>(null);

    ref.getReference().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        value.set(snapshot.getValue());
        latch.countDown();
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        exception.set(error.toException());
        latch.countDown();
      }
    });

    latch.await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if (exception.get() != null) {
      // handle error
    }

    Object result = value.get();
    // return result to user
```

I would recommend moving all the synchronization logic (with the latch and the atomic refs) into a new reusable class, so the code becomes simple and more readable.

Comment: I think this blocks the code until the reading completes from *Firebase*, is it the best practise to follow here ?

Comment: If you wish to read something from the database upon receiving a request, and send the data back in the HTTP response, this is the only way to implement it. If you know the reference you're going to read ahead of time, you can have a listener registered on it which updates some in-memory data structure, and your HTTP controller can read from that data structure.

Comment: @Rajesh If you are using Servlet 3.0 and you return a `CompleteableFuture` from your controller, the http processing thread will be freed up to continue processing new requests while the Firebase admin sdk runs from its own threads. This avoids your limited number of Servlet threads from blocking on round trip calls to Firebase and massively increases throughput. Here is an example https://nickebbitt.github.io/blog/2017/03/22/async-web-service-using-completable-future